# "The selected file is not supported" on apk install

Tags: android, apk

A client sent me a screenshot of an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOSdO.jpg) on apk installation. The phone he was using is a Samsung edge G935 (Android Version 7.0)

The apps min version is 19 and max is 25, so I don't think its an os compatibility issue.

I tried to look for this specific error everywhere but I couldn't find anything related to apk installation

Comment: Which FileManager he is using? and provide detail of phone.

Comment: @Rasi could it be possible that he is using some kind of a third party file manager ? Any type of details you would need for the phone? other than its android version ?

Comment: Yes that might be the problem with 3rd party file manager. As you can see error is not saying App can't be installed. Yes manufacturer of phone and phone model

Comment: @Rasi its a S7 edge G935 (android 7.0)

Comment: And name of file manager

Comment: @Rasi no idea, that client just sends a screenshot and expects me to guess the problem

Comment: Your problem is resolved? Just last question did you sent signed build?

Comment: @Rasi yes I did, its a V1 sign. I didn't hear back from the user yet

Comment: i have the same problem. we have a nbunch of devices with android 7, same model exactly, by on some the same ap wont open because of this. ave no idea whats happening